# Lync SDK intercept file

Tags: c#, .net, lync, lync-2010

I need to intercept file using MSPL and Lync SDK. I can intercept and get content of usual text message, but when it comes to file transfer, Content property for Response/Request contains only some information about file (e.g. file name, file size), but not real content. Is there any possibility to get transferred file content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do the same thing too, but I saw here that you cannot receive files programmatically and you can only do it through the Lync UI.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicatorsdk/thread/984e53c4-a19d-48b6-8d56-5b0428a11f52/